# How to install latest service stack open source dll

Tags: c#, service, servicestack, servicestack-bsd

Anybody knows if this is the latest free version of servicestack:

Nuget Command:

Install-Package ServiceStack -Version 3.9.71

[Nuget Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack/3.9.71)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes 3.9.71 is the latest BSD (OpenSource) version of ServiceStack. As per [the v3 documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3) you can install using:

> Install-Package ServiceStack -Version 3.9.71

If you have NuGet 2.8+ you will need to use the `-IgnoreDependencies` flag too.

> Install-Package ServiceStack -IgnoreDependencies -Version 3.9.71

Comment: Thanks, very precise answer.

Comment: Inside your packages.config file, be sure to add allowedVersions="(,4.0)" to any of your ServiceStack dependencies. This way, if you ever run an "Update-Package" command you won't risk having NuGet auto-upgrade you to the latest 4.0+ versions. See https://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning ("Constraining Upgrades to Allowed Versions" near the bottom of the page) for more details.